# Eclipse with CXF 3.X

Tags: eclipse, cxf

I work with Eclipse as IDE,
I created a web service with Apache CXF , Now I want upgrade to Apache CXF 3.0.2.
It seems eclipse does not support CXF 3.X(not even Eclipse Mars).

The main problem is that the command wsdl2java is necessary for me.

Anybody knows what's the solution?

Thanks in advance.